# retrofit request @Part and @Query in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I want to send Image as form-data and userId as Params in retrofit android.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5fwT.png)I have tried many solution but did not got any success. here is my code and api.

@Multipart
@POST("upload/profile")
fun uploadProfilePhoto(@Part image: MultipartBody.Part, @Query("userId") userId: String): Call

```
    val photoContent = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file)
    val photo = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.name, photoContent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error in my case. actually when we post multipart parameter then we have to match our formData name with backend in the API. in my case it was "image/png" `val photo = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.name, photoContent)`

Answer (score 1):

send your request like this

```
val userId: RequestBody = userId.toRequestBody("multipart/formdata".toMediaTypeOrNull())

val image = file.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val photo = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("images", file.name, image)
```

Use this userID as requestBody and photo for image

```
@Multipart
    @POST("upload/profile")
    fun uploadProfilePhoto(
        @Part image: MultipartBody.Part,
        @Part("userId") userId: RequestBody
    ): Call<LoginSignUpGeneralResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must check `uploadProfilePhoto` function return type.
it should be Call and T should define.
If you still get error information. display more. like **breakpoint debug** or **postman**

edit

```
interface UploadImage{
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload/profile")
    fun upload(@Query("userId") userId: String, @Part part: 
        MultipartBody.Part) : Call<LoginSignUpGeneralResponse>
}

val call = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build()
.create(UploadImage::class.java)
.upload(userId,image)
call.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginSignUpGeneralResponse>{
        override fun onResponse(//params){TODO()}
        override fun onFailure(//params){TODO()}
})
```

Comment: thanks for your response. my uploadProfilePhoto function return type is Call<LoginSignUpGeneralResponse> and after hitting the call, controller never comes in success nor in failer case.

Comment: this is my postman. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V28aAS84AarMIfaaPQRrByFxQ0HSt-fN/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GVtg1dqgsu97OTc5mvnJc2YKoh8Jq2hm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your Api is worked normal and  code is current. I think the call is not added to the queue check the call execute() or enqueue()

Comment: this is my api request function ` fun  uploadPhoto(userId: String, image: MultipartBody.Part){
        val userDataService = RetrofitClient.service
        val call = userDataService.uploadPhoto(image,userId)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, resp: Response<T>) {

                if (resp.body() != null) {
                }else {
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
    }`

Comment: I changed my answer It can help you. I don't know you Why not define T

Comment: your solution is giving same response as mine i.e application is running without going to success and failure block..

Comment: comment section does not allow long text so I just replace My "LoginSignUpGeneralResponse" response class  with T. it is defined

Comment: try Breakpoint debug `call` `onResponse` `onFailure`

Comment: I have tried break points onResponse and onFailure but it is not coming in these blocks as I said earlier and no app crash or exceptions occurs.

Comment: I got this every time when I hit the request call                                   W/cybersafefamil: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/System: A resource failed to call close.

Comment: cannot help you. it work normal in my app.